# json_encode particular part of array

Tags: php, arrays, json, echo

```
$array = array("Real" => array("Alonso","Zidan"),"Inter" => "Zanetti", "Roma" => "Toti");
$json=json_encode($array);
echo $json
```

By this way I am reading all the data, but how can I read the data of 
only `Real` or `Inter`?

For example, if it is json_decoded I can do so:

1. For `Inter`:

   ```
   echo $array['Inter'];
   ```
2. For `Real`:

   ```
   foreach($array["Real"] as $real){ 
       echo $real."<br>";
   }
   ```

How can I do the same with `json_encode()`?

Comment: Using javascript I suppose?

Comment: Why can't you just read it from `$array`? It's unclear what your actual problem is

Comment: Get what you want and then encode it.

Comment: put values in different arrays and encode them. For eg: `echo json_encode($array['Inter']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question you need to output the json`d object.

**Input**

```
$input = '{"Real":["Alonso","Zidan"],"Inter":"Zanetti","Roma":"Toti"}';
```

**In php**:

```
// Second true is for array return, not object)
$string = json_decode($input, true) 
echo $string['Inter'];
```

**In Javascript** (jQuery):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(input);
if (obj != undefined) {
    echo obj['Inter'];
}
```

**UPD:**

If you need to get an json in all arrays you need to make follow:

```
$array = array("Real" => array("Alonso","Zidan"),"Inter" => "Zanetti", "Roma" => "Toti");
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = json_encode($value);
}
```

After this code all variables in array will be json`ed and you can echo them in any time

Comment: So what do you need for it. Just echo it and that`s all. You can add die after echo to ensure that nothing else will not outputed.

Answer (score 2):

[`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) returns a string, so you can't access its parts without parsing the string. But you can do the following instead:

```
echo json_encode($array['Inter']);
```